# Printing out the elements of any array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way in Java to have a method which takes an array - and here's the important part - primitive or not primitive, and prints out its elements? I tried a bunch of things, including generics, but I can't seem to get around the fact that some of these arrays might have primitive values.

Here's what I have so far, although it's not that useful since it doesn't compile:

```
    public static void dumpArray(Object a)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

This takes into account that any array is a subtype of an object.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

It simply has overloads for arrays of every basic type, plus one more for `Object[]`.

```
static String toString(boolean[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
static String toString(byte[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
static String toString(char[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
static String toString(double[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
static String toString(float[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
static String toString(int[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
static String toString(long[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
static String toString(Object[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
static String toString(short[] a)
          Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
```

---

If you really *need* it to be a single method and not a collection of overloads then you'd have to have a parameter of type `Object` and use reflection to see what the actual type is and then call the appropriate overload.

```
public static String toString(Object a) throws
    InvocationTargetException,
    NoSuchMethodException,
    IllegalAccessException
{
    Class clazz = Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass())
         ? Object[].class : a.getClass();
    Method method = Arrays.class.getMethod("toString", new Class[] { clazz } );
    return (String)method.invoke(null, new Object[] { a });
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/I7hHE)

Comment: +1; and here's the link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Could you possibly elaborate on how I would use reflection? I had been trying to do that earlier but it wasn't working out.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void dumpArray(Object[] a)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

You just had to change the parameter so that it was an array.
The `System.out.println(Object o)` method prints out o.toString(), which in the case of numbers is the String corresponding to the number.

You can convert int[] to Integer[] with a different loop, for example.

Comment: Well, you can convert the primitive arrays into Object arrays using a for loop.

Comment: The only problem with that is that I want to be able to do all operations from within the method, so I don't want to have to worry about conversion beforehand... Or do you mean I can convert from within the method?

Comment: Oh, then you can overload the methods with different type parameters; or use Mark Byers' answer, even I, a competitor with a different answer, +1'd it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done using `java.lang.reflect.Array`. Here is the code snippet:

```
private static void printArray(Object array) {
    if(!array.getClass().isArray()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int n = Array.getLength(array);
    for (int i = 0;  i < n;  i++) {
        System.out.println(Array.get(array, i));
    }
}
```

And this is the example how to call it:

```
    printArray(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
    printArray(new String[] {"aaa", "bbb"});
```

But it is a "bad practice". Take a look in implementation of `Arrays.toString()` they implemented one version for `Object[]` and special version for each primitive type although all versions are almost identical.

So, think good if you really want to use the solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that once again demonstrates how easy it is to overlook something in the class libraries.

Instead of rolling out your own code, just use `Arrays.deepToString()` which does exactly that.